# Weird JSON encoding issue on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8

I have an issue on Android 4.1.2 where a JSON object given to us by our REST API gets encoded weirdly when sending back.

This is the snippet of json I'm getting:

```
"cost":{
    "amount": 0,
    "currency": "GBP"
}
```

I'm wanting to pretty much just pass this particular snippet back the same way (modifying other parts of the json), but this is what I get on Android 4.1.2:

```
"cost":"{amount=0, currency=GBP}"
```

The function I believe is causing this weird encoding is here:

```
        private StringEntity getEntityForRequest(final Payment payment, final PaymentDelegate delegate) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            MyApplication.getContext().addApplicationInformationToJSONObject(json);
            StringEntity entity = null;
            try {
                entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                payment.markAsFailed("Reservation failed, data returned not expected.");
                save(payment);

                if (delegate != null) {
                    delegate.onFailure(new MyError(MyError.DEFAULT_STATUS, MyError.DEFAULT_TYPE, "Payment error", "Error during reservation"));
                }


            }
            return entity;
        }
```

This is the addApplicationIformationToJSONObject function:

```
/**
 * Adds system information to a JSON object.
 */
public void addApplicationInformationToJSONObject(JSONObject json) {

    try {
        try {
            json.put("app_version", getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            json.put("app_version", "Unknown");
        }
        json.put("device", getDeviceName());
        json.put("os_type", "android");
        json.put("os_version", String.format("%d", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
        json.put("device_id", Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        MyLog.e("MyApplication", "Error when adding system information to JSON");
    }
}
```

What's causing this weird encoding?

How can I modify the code to avoid issues like this?

Comment: I first thought this was on Samsung Galaxy S2 only, but I've verified (using the emulator) that this can be reproduced on any Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Need more clarity on your question

Comment: what does your `addApplicationInformationToJSONObject(json)` method do?

Comment: @agamov I've included that function now.

Comment: @IndraKumarS what specifically do you need more clarity on? I tried my best.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. It seems older version interprets that cost snippet as a string rather than a JSONObject. Doing this seems to solve the issue:

```
ticketObject.remove("cost");
ticketObject.put("cost", new JSONObject(getCost()));
```